# Check if Overlap in Schedules

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table that lists employee schedules. I need to write a query to determine if more than one person was working on the same task at the same time. My data is like the following:

```
EmployeeID  JobID   StartTime   EndTime     M   Tu  W   Th  F   Sa  Su
======================================================================
10001       201     12:00:00    14:00:00    1   1   1   1   1   0   0
10001       202     15:00:00    17:00:00    1   1   1   1   1   0   0
10001       202     17:30:00    18:30:00    1   1   1   1   1   0   0
10002       202     16:00:00    18:00:00    1   1   1   1   1   0   0
```

The gist of what I was trying is below, but obviously this is not correct. I just can't figure out where to even start looking for a solution to this problem.

```
select * 
from Table1 
where (JobID=JobID) AND 
    (StartTime > StartTime AND StartTime < EndTime) OR
    (EndTime > StartTime AND EndTime < EndTime)
```

I do need to take days into consideration as well, but that should be pretty straight forward once I figure out how to do the rest of the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close but you need to reference the same table twice. So, you need a `JOIN` to represent your overlap table. Try something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 AS t1
JOIN Table1 AS t1_overlap ON
    t1_overlap.JobID = t1.JobID
    AND t1_overlap.EmployeeID != t1.EmployeeID
    AND (t1_overlap.StartTime BETWEEN  t1.StartTime AND t1.EndTime
        OR t1_overlap.EndTime BETWEEN  t1.StartTime AND t1.EndTime)
    AND t1_overlap.M = t1.M
    AND t1_overlap.Tu = t1.Tu
    AND t1_overlap.W = t1.W
    AND t1_overlap.Th = t1.Th
    AND t1_overlap.F = t1.F
    AND t1_overlap.Sa = t1.Sa
    AND t1_overlap.Su = t1.Su
```

Comment: No such luck. See comment above to SlimsGhost.

Comment: @doby48, check my edit I added some logic to select different employees for the overlap table

Answer (score 0):

One quick way to do this is with a self-join, since you need to compare multiple rows from the same table that have the same JobID. Try this:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
inner join table1 t2 on t1.JobID = t2.JobID
where (
    t1.StartTime BETWEEN t2.StartTime and t2.EndTime
    or t1.EndTime BETWEEN t2.StartTime and t2.EndTime
)
```

You can also do this more efficiently if you use Window Functions, but they are a bit more advanced, so the above is a straightforward way to achieve what you want.

Comment: This is giving me all results in the database plus duplicating some. So for example I have 2 people working on Job ID 3. EmployeeID 1001 from 05:00:00 - 09:00:00 and EmployeeID 1002 from 15:00:00 - 19:00:00. Nobody else worked on that JobID. However, both of those values are being returned to me using the query you provided.

Comment: that's what i would expect, given that "an overlap" requires two records. i see you've accepted an answer, but if you can explain what you need i can still help, like do you want just the list of distinct JobID's, or what?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to `self join` on the same table like others have mentioned and make sure to join on these following conditions:

```
SELECT distinct
     t1.EmployeeID as FirstEmployee,
     t2.EmployeeID as SecondEmployee,
     t1.StartTime as FirstEmployeeStartTime,
     t2.StartTime as SecondEmployeeStartTime,         
     t1.EndTime as FirstEmployeeEndTime,
     t2.EndTime as SecondEmployeeEndTime
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table1 t2 ON t1.JobID = t2.JobID
    AND t1.employeeid <> t2.employeeid
    AND (
        t1.StartTime BETWEEN t2.StartTime
            AND t2.EndTime
        OR t1.EndTime BETWEEN t2.StartTime
            AND t2.EndTime
        )
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a0647/8/0)

Answer (score 0):

So, you already know you need a self join as all the other answers tell you. However, I didn't see any of the current answers test for overlapping the correct way.

Any 2 ranges overlap if (and only if) the first start is smaller then the second end, while the second start is smaller then the first end.
Therefor, you want to test your start date against the end date if the other records of the table, and the end date against the start date of the other records in the table.

Check out the wiki for the `overlap` tag to see what I mean.